# Java 8 stream min() and anyMatch() (or sth like that) in one line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects with the following structure:

```
public class ExampleObject {

    private boolean someBoolean;
    private int someInteger;
    // getters, setters, constructor...
}
```

I need a method, that will return the integer -1 if any of the objects has the someBoolean field set to true, otherwise return the minimum of someInteger.

I could do it with simple for loop, is there a way to do it with one single stream? My problem was that both anyMatch and min() is terminating the stream.

Comment: so what is the problem of iterating twice? show us the simple for loop anyway. And yes, there is a way to do with a single stream operation, but you will _not_ like it + it will not  be short-circuiting operation like the for loop (without some dirty code). Stick to what you already have IMO

Comment: `int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (ExampleObject object : examples) {
            if (object.isSomeBoolean()) {
                return -1;
            }
            min = Math.max(min, object.getSomeInteger());
        }
        return min;`... not sure if streams would improve that.

Comment: A for loop seems like an entirely reasonable approach in this situtation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `someInteger` is non-negative, you can map each instance to either -1 or `someInteger` based on the value of the `boolean` property, and find the minimum:

```
OptionalInt min = list.mapToInt (o -> o.getSomeBoolean () ? -1 : o.getSomeInteger())
                      .min();
```

If `someInteger` can be negative, you can map the instances for which the `boolean` property it `true` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and change the output to `-1` if it's equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: problem is that this is _not_ short-circuiting, like a for loop is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keen on *short-circuiting*, then the possible way is to split `anyMatch()` and `min()`. But note, this **may need to traverse the list twice** if none of the boolean element is set to true.

Below is a snippet,

```
OptionalInt optionalint = OptionalInt.of(-1);
if (!myList.stream().anyMatch(hd -> hd.bool)) { // If nothing matches, optionalint remains -1
   optionalint = myList.stream().mapToInt(he -> he.num).min();
}
//Other logic with optionalInt
```